# Cannot Access Laravel Storage Directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-storage

I'm using Laravel 5.7. On my localhost, my storage works fine, and all images show as well, but on my host, new images don't display.

I use below code inisde the `blade.php` file:

```
{{ asset("storage/$slider") }}
```

On my localhost it shows images:

```
localhost:8000/storage/sliders/HKeGwcvnXbjuiA6g9wsjnoqphJc5DGup78D92b4F.jpeg
```

On my website I cannot access:

http://mywebsite.com/storage/sliders/HKeGwcvnXbjuiA6g9wsjnoqphJc5DGup78D92b4F.jpeg

Comment: why you cannot access it? Is there any error messages?

Comment: Unless there's a storage directory in the public folder, it's not directly accessible. You'll need to either create a storage folder in public, or find another way to serve the files. It could be accessible locally due to your site/folder structure.

Comment: @Smankusors it shows 404 page.

Comment: @aynbar there is a foder on my host and my images uploaded as well: `storage/app/public/sliders`

Comment: I'm using shared host.

Comment: No, the folder should be in `/public/storage`. Anything not in `/public` will not be directly accessible, and will need to go through a route or controller. -- Edit: Whoops, never mind, apparently that's something newer than the version I'm using. Make sure you've followed: `You should create a symbolic link at  public/storage which points to this directory. You may create the link using the  php artisan storage:link command.`

Comment: wait... how do you run the server locally? which document root is localhost:8000?

Comment: you should use `{{ asset("storage/app/public/sliders/$slider") }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now I use this route and It worked:

```
Route::get('storage/sliders/{filename}', function ($filename)
{

    $path = storage_path('app/public/sliders/' . $filename);

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```

if you have another sub-directories you can use:

```
Route::get('storage/{path}/{filename}', function ($path,$filename)
{

    $path = storage_path('app/public/'.$path.'/' . $filename);

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```